# Ubuntu 20.04: “EXT4-fs (sdb2): VFS: Can’t find ext4 file system”-error

Tags: boot, partitioning, ext4

I am quite new to Linux and have recently started to use Ubuntu. At first it worked, but for the last three days, every time I started my computer I get in emergency mode and  this error message appears: “EXT4-fs (sdb2): VFS: Can’t find ext4 file system”. I tried to follow the instructions from other users that had the same problem, but it somehow doesn’t work for me.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you will have to provide some more information. Boot the system from the Ubuntu install disk/usb and choose try Ubuntu. Copy and paste the output of `lsblk’ into your question. Mount your root partition and copy and paste the contents of /etc/fstab from that partition into your question. Also, if you understood what you were doing, please describe as best you can what you have already tried.